# How to store JavaScript files and call in .NET to use Ajax

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, database, visual-studio-2010

I am newish to coding and am working on a project in Visual Studio 2010 using VB. I want to implement Ajax in my solution and I think that I have to use .js files to do this. My question is, provided I can get appropriate JavaScripts to build the files, how should I store them in my solution and how do I actually call a class that I have created.  I presume the .js file would be separate to the .aspx and .aspx.vb files.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have searched online but I cannot find anything that shows how to create the .js file and then run it in the appropriate page.  Just to give you a taste of my plans, I have a user database which is represented in the website via a gridview table.  I want to use Ajax to enable me to drag and drop rows in the table to reposition users.  Upon reposition the database will need to update to show where each user is now positioned in the table.  I will be using a field called "UserID" for this which is an int.

Sorry for rambling on.  Just trying to be as concise as possible.  Thanks guys

Comment: I cannot understand what you want

Comment: Just go and get any book or online course about HTML, JS, CSS, asp.net basics, try to apply new knowledge on your project and return with questions when you will have at least some understanding of how that everything works. What you are asking about could be found in any basic book and explaining everything will take too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspx basically uses html semantics (with some cs or vb things inside of it), so you can include a `script` tag like in any html file. For example, you can have (for me it is in C# and in my master page) :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="_Site.master.cs" Inherits="MyProject.SiteMaster" %>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">
<head runat="server">
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    ...
    <script src="~/Scripts/External/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="otherScripts" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

and my global script is in a folder (in the same project as my project file) named "Scripts". Moreover, I have a placeholder in order to add some small scripts specific to one page.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Samuel.  Is it a case then that, in my basic website anyway, there is one main .js file where you keep all the methods you write for the entire project.  You then reference the .js page in the master page (which i am using) and through out the project you simply call individual methods from this page - in the case of your example "jquery-1.4.1.js   Would that be the general idea anyway? I'm trying to get a starting point and, as I'm sure you know, that is often the hardest part.

Comment: Yes exactly : if it is a small website with very few scripts, you can keep all your functions in a single file. For my needs, I always split my functions many small javascript files and in production (this is why I have 2 other folders in my script folder!), I concatenate and minifies them with [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/).